# Virtualbox Guest Additions Installation error

Tags: 12.10, virtualbox, guest-additions

I am having a lot of troubles to have my virtualbox guest additions installed, I got this message:

```
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 4.2.10 Guest Additions for Linux..........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 4.2.10 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Removing existing VirtualBox DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Removing existing VirtualBox non-DKMS kernel modules ...done.
Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel modules ...done.
Doing non-kernel setup of the Guest Additions ...done.
Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions ...fail!
(modprobe vboxguest failed)
Installing the Window System drivers
Installing X.Org Server 1.13 modules ...done.
Setting up the Window System to use the Guest Additions ...done.
You may need to restart the hal service and the Window System (or just restart
the guest system) to enable the Guest Additions.

Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ...done.
```

My ubuntu is 12.10, virtualbox is 4.2.10 and so the guest additions. I have tried the usual solutions as updating the linux headers, but nothing...

```
apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

returns:

```
build-essential is already the newest version.
dkms is already the newest version.
linux-headers-generic is already the newest version.
```

This is the output of /var/log/vboxadd-install.log

```
Uninstalling modules from DKMS
Attempting to install using DKMS

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.2.10/source ->
             /usr/src/vboxguest-4.2.10

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.5.0-25-generic -C /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/build M=/var   /lib/dkms/vboxguest/4.2.10/build...........
cleaning build area....

DKMS: build completed.

vboxguest:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxsf.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxvideo.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Creating user for the Guest Additions.
Creating udev rule for the Guest Additions kernel module.
```

It happened to me also with previous versions of virtualbox and guest additions. I really need this thing working and I am really desperate right now! Many thanks!

I add here more info:

```
$ cat VBoxGuestAdditions.log
Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions ...fail!
(modprobe vboxguest failed)
Starting VirtualBox Guest Addition service VirtualBox Additions module not loaded!
$ sudo modprobe vboxguest
FATAL: Error inserting vboxguest (/lib/modules/3.5.0-25-generic/updates/dkms/vboxguest.ko): No such device
```

Many thanks

Comment: There should be a couple hints in var/log/VBoxGuestAdditions.log . Could you post the relevant log entries?